# How to avoid adding a reference field in very small entries (thus avoiding doubling collection size)?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a `User` class that accumulates lots of `DataTime` entries in some `List<DateTime> Entries` field.

Occasionally, I need to get last 12 `Entries` (or less, if not reached to 12). It can get to very large numbers.

I can add new `Entry` object to dedicated collection, but then I have to add `ObjectId User` field to refer the related user.

It seems like a big overhead, for each entry that holds only a `DateTime`, to add another field of `ObjectId`. It may double the collection size.

As I occasionally need to quickly get only last 12 entries of 100,000 for instance, I cannot place these entries in a per-user collection like:

```
class PerUserEntries {
    public ObjectId TheUser;
    public List<DateTime> Entries;
}
```

Because it's not possible to fetch only N entries from an embedded array in a mongo query, AFAIK (if I'm wrong, it would be very gladdening!).

So am I doomed to double my collection size or is there a way around it?

#### Update, according to `@profesor79`'s answer:

If your answer works, that will be perfect! but unfortunately it fails...

Since I needed to filter on the user entity as well, here is what I did:

With this data:

```
class EndUserRecordEx {
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName;
    public List<EncounterData> Encounters
}
```

I am trying this:

```
var query = EuBatch.Find(u => u.UserName == endUser.UserName)
    .Project<BsonDocument>(
        Builders<EndUserRecordEx>.Projection.Slice(
            u => u.Encounters, 0, 12));

var queryString = query.ToString();
var requests = await query.ToListAsync(); // MongoCommandException
```

This is the query I get in `queryString`:

```
find({ "UserName" : "qXyF2uxkcESCTk0zD93Sc+U5fdvUMPow" }, { "Encounters" : { "$slice" : [0, 15] } })
```

Here is the error (the `MongoCommandException.Result`):

```
{ 
    {
        "_t" : "OKMongoResponse",
        "ok" : 0,
        "code" : 9,
        "errmsg" : "Syntax error, incorrect syntax near '17'.",
        "$err" : "Syntax error, incorrect syntax near '17'."
    }
}
```

#### Update: problem identified...

Recently, Microsoft announced their [DocumentDB protocol support for MongoDB](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-protocol-mongodb/). Apparently, it [doesn't support yet all `projection` operators](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-mongodb-guidelines/#_support-matrix). I tried it with `mLab.com`, and it works.

Comment: what version of mongo?

Comment: @profesor79, let's assume 3.2

Comment: Can you use a `Dictionary`?

Comment: @KevinWallis, how would it help?

Comment: I haven't used mongodb for long ... 
So i maybe thought that it is possible to use a `Dicitionary` instead a `List` this `Dictionary` has the `ObjectId` as Key and the `List` of `DateTime` as Value.

Comment: @KevinWallis, still, it's a `List<DateTime>` that's embedded within a `Dictionary` value, so the `bson` would look like `{ "userKey" : [ ... ] }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PerUserEntries` as this is a valuable document structure.
To get part of that array we need to add projection to query, so we can get only `x` elements and this is done server side.

Please see snippet below:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // To directly connect to a single MongoDB server
        // or use a connection string
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<PerUserEntries>("tar");

        var newData = new PerUserEntries();
        newData.Entries = new List<DateTime>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            newData.Entries.Add(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(i));
        }

        collection.InsertOne(newData);

        var list =
            collection.Find(new BsonDocument())
                .Project<BsonDocument>
                (Builders<PerUserEntries>.Projection.Slice(x => x.Entries, 0, 3))
                .ToList();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

   public class PerUserEntries
    {
        public List<DateTime> Entries;
        public ObjectId TheUser;
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: If it works it's perfect! but I get error... see my update